# Web3: No provider set

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm writing a script using web3 (1.0.0-beta.27), where I'm trying to deploy a contract and listen for an event.

Here's the simplified version of the code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

let web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
let contract = await MyContract.deploy({data: code})
  .send({from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000});

contract.events.MyEvent((error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
}
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Error: No provider set.
> at Subscription.subscribe (/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/src/subscription.js:199:20)
> at Contract._on (/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:634:18)

My understanding was that passing the URL to the Web3 constructor would set the provider, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an `HttpProvider` when creating `Web3`. Change

`let web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');`

to

`let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));`

or, you can set the provider after creating `Web3`:

```
const web3 = new Web3();

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  

The [web3 documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#setprovider) seems to imply that both forms are equivalent.